# RDP session Flickering - Only one user

Tags: windows, vpn, remote-desktop, rdp

So, This is a tricky one.

I use a system where users connects via VPN to a Terminal Server on an other site. It is working fine for everybody but one user. For this user the screen is flickering/flashing/refreshing constantly and the session is unusable. It did work two days ago. No changes know by the user since then. Computer in Win10 and Server 2016

What I did is:

```
play around with caching, resolution, color depth (in mstsc settings) ... > same flickering
erase the remote desktop cache > same flickering
log with mstsc on an other server with his computer > works fine
try to connect with his user on my own computer > same flickering
download the other remote desktop from microsoft store > same flickering
try to update network card driver, video driver > all up to date
windows update > same flickering
check network settings > everything is fine
properly sign out the session of the user on the server > same flickering
erase the user profile from the server > same flickering
```

Performance of the PC are all good. No overload network, ram or cpu

So I am clueless...any other ideas woudl be greatly appreciated.

Ben

Comment: i'm dealing with a similar situation. i've figured out that if i disconnect everyone else from the server, the flickering stops and the session is usable. still looking for a permanent fix but maybe this will help for a little bit

Comment: also, you can open task manager using an on screen keyboard so you can kick everyone else out, if you're having problems with that

Comment: found this and it helped me. check if you have winzip 20.0 installed : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/42c46af6-7673-4036-8f79-b50562ff0fa0/windows-server-2012-remote-desktop-flickercrash?forum=winserver8gen

Answer (score 0):

We've experienced similar issues.

We were able to resolve it by both lowering the graphics as by changing the VPN to a Split Tunnel. Because of that the bandwith of the VPN tunnel was solely used for the RDP session.